# django template: how to enclose a variable

Tags: django, templates

I would like to make a sequence of variables within a  for loop such as name0, name1, .... How do I do that? Thanks.

```
    {% for i in '1234567890' %}
        {% if name{{forloop.counter0}} %}
        ...
        {% endif %}
        ...
        {{name{{forloop.counter0}}}}
        ...
    {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see, the Django templating language tries hard to keep you from doing what you're trying to do, encouraging you to do your data processing in your view code, instead of your templates.  For your example, in your view code, you might try doing:

```
context['names'] = [name for name in names[:10]]
```

...instead of creating individual variables for each name.

Then in your template:

```
{% for name in names %}
    {% if name %}
    ...
    {% endif %}
    ...
    {{name}}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

As far as I can tell, that would have the same effect as your code, but you would be doing your aggregation of the names in the view, instead of the template.  If I'm reading the intent of your code wrongly, please provide more context, but it doesn't seem like you're doing anything that *requires* template logic.

Comment: Well, what I am trying to do is: I have a long list of form input fields, each with name "name0", "name1", ... I don't want to list them one by one in the html file. It's better to use the template for loop. Am I right, or is there a better way to do it in the view code? thanks.

Comment: Tough to say without seeing your actual code.  I assume you mean that the form gets submitted and there is a number fields that come back that gets determined by what the client submits, your best bet may be to parse out the dynamic field from the response in the view. For example, you could say `names = [name for name in request.POST if name.startswith('name')]`

Answer (score 2):

is as simple as

```
{{ name }}{{ forloop.counter0 }}
```

for the if, you should use the "with" statement:

```
{% with name|add:forloop.counter0 as if_test %}
{% if if_test %}
... <!-- do whatever you need to do here -->
```

all this must be inside your for loop